# Console display on Fedora 31 server doesn't work - x.org broken? Driver?

Tags: linux, display, fedora

I have unintentionally built a headless Fedora 31 server. When it boots, I get the bios display, then the grub menu to choose one of the kernels installed, then nothing. The monitor does NOT say "No Signal" - it thinks there's a signal present. I expected Ctrl/Alt/F3 (or F2-5) to give me a text console, but no, nothing happens. This monitor & keyboard are on a KVM, and if I switch to another Fedora 31 machine, the alt console keys work. And I can SSH to this machine and run it all day & night with no issues. But there's no text-mode console (or any other kind of console) available.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this. There's nothing interesting in messages.log, that I can see.

Here's an excerpt from lspci:

```
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF116 [GeForce GT 640 OEM] (rev a1)
```

I'm pretty sure the Intel video is the built-in controller on the motherboard. Plugging into that results in "No Signal" at the monitor, always. All the troubleshooting I've tried has been while plugged into the NVIDIA card.

What else should I post to help troubleshoot this?

Here's an extract from Xorg.0.log:

````
[    21.491] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    21.499] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
[    21.499] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
[    21.499] (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
[    21.499] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20200515
[    21.513] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
[    21.513] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx; using a maximum of 4 threads
[    21.513] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    21.513] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[    21.513] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    21.514] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 using monitor section Monitor1
[    21.514] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VGA1
[    21.514] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[    21.514] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[    21.514] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 has no monitor section
[    21.515] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1
[    21.515] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI2 has no monitor section
[    21.515] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI2
[    21.515] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI3 has no monitor section
[    21.515] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI3
[    21.515] (II) intel(0): Output DP2 has no monitor section
[    21.515] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP2
[    21.515] (II) intel(0): Output DP3 has no monitor section
[    21.515] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP3
[    21.515] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[    21.516] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[    21.516] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[    21.516] (==) intel(0): TearFree disabled
[    21.516] (==) intel(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    21.516] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    21.516] (II) Loading sub module "dri3"
[    21.516] (II) LoadModule: "dri3"
[    21.516] (II) Module "dri3" already built-in
[    21.516] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    21.516] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    21.516] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    21.516] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[    21.516] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[    21.516] (II) Module "present" already built-in
[    21.518] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Ivybridge (gen7, gt2) backend
[    21.518] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[    21.518] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    21.518] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[    21.518] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[    21.519] (==) intel(0): Display hotplug detection enabled
[    21.519] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    21.519] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[    21.519] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[    21.519] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 DRI3 enable```
````

Comment: Forgot to mention that I've run ```dnf update``` a few times since encountering this issue, most recently this morning, and followed that with a reboot. No change. But I have a shiny new kernel.

Comment: Why don't you reinstall the server with better intentions?

Comment: I would reinstall but I've done a lot of elaborate customization use bcache and an SSD as the cache device, as well as other stuff, so I'm reluctant to reinstall.

Comment: From the error messages, it seems like the NVIDIA module might be the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

harrymc was right, the driver was the issue. For some reason, the most recent versions of the driver are not supported. I was trying to use `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.132.run` but no go.

I had to download 
`NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.108.run` and the patcher too- 
`inttf-nvidia-patcher.sh`

These are some of the steps:

```
wget -O inttf-nvidia-patcher.sh https://nvidia.if-not-true-then-false.com/patcher/inttf-nvidia-patcher.sh
chmod +x inttf-nvidia-patcher.sh
./inttf-nvidia-patcher.sh -v 340.108
./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.108-patched-kernel-5.9.run
```

It says it's for the 5.9 and up kernels, but I have 5.8.18, so that might be why I had issues with libglx.so. The installer griped about the library not being a symlink. So I looked and no, it's not, its the actual library. So to make it happy I renamed it to its version number and make a symlink in the same directory. Then it took it. I also apparently didn't have flex or bison, so I installed those:

```
dnf whatprovides flex
dnf install flex-2.6.4-3.fc31.x86_64
dnf whatprovides bison
dnf install bison-3.4.1-2.fc31.x86_64
```

So now it works, after some pain, and this is the result:

```
[root@simak NVIDIA]# nvidia-smi
Wed Dec 16 10:33:36 2020
+------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.108    Driver Version: 340.108        |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 8400GS      Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   45C   P12    N/A /  N/A |     87MiB /  1023MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I'm successfully running KDE now.
Thanks all.